# Python raw_input doesn't work in VIM

Tags: python, vim

I wrote a simply program:

```
print "What is your name?"
name = raw_input()
print "Hello %s!" % name
```

When I run it directly in VIM I get:

> What is your name?
>   Hello print "What is your name?"!

I can't type anything. Program stops with "Hit any key to close this window..."
What is going here? Python 2.7, Win10, VIM 7.4.

Comment: Which vim command are you using to run it?

Comment: :w !python - I have F5 shortcut in my _vimrc file. When I type this command in VIM console I get an error: "What is your name?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
shell returned 1"

Comment: Do you understand what `:w !python` does?